# Change number of columns of AsymmetricGridView

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView). I did all that he said and expecting a nice `gridView` with 4 columns. but what I've got was a 2-column sloppy `gridView` like below:

[image]

and this is my code of changing `columnCount` and `columnWidth`

```
listView.setRequestedColumnCount(4);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        int column_width = (int)dpWidth / 4;

        listView.setRequestedColumnWidth(Utils.dpToPx(this, column_width));
        listView.determineColumns();

        listView.setAllowReordering(true);
        listView.isAllowReordering(); // true
```

**so How can I change `columnCount` and `columnWidth` of this `view`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((AsymmetricGridView)findViewById(R.id.installed_app_list)).setRequestedColumnCount(5);
```